# Wrong number of columns when importing csv file

Tags: r, csv

I have a dataset of 17 columns and 72920 rows. The dataset was saved form Excel to csv format.
I then load it in R 3.1.2:

```
old<-read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
```

> str(old)
>   'data.frame':   72920 obs. of  1 variable:
>    $ OID.LO.MAG.PCR.WAT.SVE.ARA.GRA.FOR.MHF.B13.B12.MTP.BI6.BI4.ALT.BI1: Factor w/ 72920 levels "1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;32.00;100;420;43;72;4821;18.18;18.555",..: 1 11112 22223 33334 44445 55556 66667 70699 71810 2 ...

The problem is that R treats my dataset as being 1 column instead of 17.
This is what my data looks like before exporting it:

```
OID LO  MAG PCR WAT SVE ARA GRA FOR MHF B13 B12 MTP BI6 BI4 ALT BI1 URB
    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   32.00   100 420 43  72  4821    18.18   18.555  1
    2   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   39.17   99  421 81  72  4886    20.14   18.586  0
    3   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   29.25   112 474 13  74  4947    132.80  18.470  0
    4   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   35.98   114 485 4   70  4997    166.54  18.213  0
    5   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   39.21   104 438 3   74  4859    54.82   18.580  1
    6   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   40.45   109 454 3   68  4971    107.65  18.216  0
    7   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   41.81   107 435 2   69  4909    46.70   18.400  0
    8   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   49.78   105 427 21  70  5009    18.36   18.636  0
    9   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   53.00   106 427 98  70  5173    13.33   18.767  0
```

I have tried exporting as txt as well, but when importing my data as a table I run into the same problem as above. 
I hope someone can help me in getting my data read correctly by R.

Comment: you need to set the separator with the argument sep = ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to set a separator argument with `sep = ";"`

More about `read.table` (and `read.csv`) can be found  [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html).

So the code will look like this:

```
old <- read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

Or instead of using `read.table` you can also use `read.csv2()` for semicolon(**;**)  separated files, or `read.csv()` for comma(**,**) separated files. In your case this would look like this:

```
old <- read.csv2(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify a separator as stated here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

```
old <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```